# Issues getting Youtube API WordPress plugin Restricted

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I’m still having no luck getting this Youtube API Restricted properly.

Every time I try to give it HTTP referrers Restrictions & add the following Website Restrictions:

https://www.ohiocannabis.com
https://www.ohiocannabis.com/*

I then get the following error in my Youtube video player on my website: http://www.ohiocannabis.com/videos

Sorry, there was a YouTube API error: The referrer https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,status&playlistId=UUkbzQe9G_drgd3QoLmHZNfw&maxResults=15&key=AIzaSyArOPULA9UG52ZQUO7ddZMxrpC6odiFW4I does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions. Please make sure you performed the steps in this video to create and save a proper server API key.

I've also tried using the IP Restriction, the IP for my website is: 107.154.147.253

But when I use that the player gives me the following error:

Sorry, there was a YouTube API error: The calling IP address 50.116.78.101 does not match the IP restrictions configured on the API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.

So who/what/where is this “Calling IP” coming from that it would have a much different IP than my website domain?

(I unrestricted it so that my videos populate for now, so you may not see that error message on my Videos page)

Any idea on what I’m doing wrong to get this plugin to Restrict & work properly?

Thank you!!

I've tried adding HTTP Restrictions and also IP Restrictions, both with no luck.

I haven't tried any code yet, not sure what to do.

Sorry, there was a YouTube API error: The referrer https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,status&playlistId=UUkbzQe9G_drgd3QoLmHZNfw&maxResults=15&key=AIzaSyArOPULA9UG52ZQUO7ddZMxrpC6odiFW4I does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions. Please make sure you performed the steps in this video to create and save a proper server API key.

Sorry, there was a YouTube API error: The calling IP address 50.116.78.101 does not match the IP restrictions configured on the API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out, I was adding a double restriction on this API by doing the HTTP and the API Restrictions option at the bottom.

I've removed the HTTP Restriction and just kept the API Restriction enabled to the Youtube Data API v3 and it seems to not be giving me the error any longer and showing all of my videos and google console is showing it is in fact now a Restricted API.

Does this sound like I did it right this time?

Thank you!